# How to make a character move smoothly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game, and I'd like to know how to make a character move more smoothly. The character can already move, but it moves really choppy; when you click the arrow key, it instantly appears 10 pixels ahead. I'd like it to move smoothly so it doesn't just "appear" 10 pixels ahead of itself.
Here is the Code:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
var canvas;
var ctx;

var up;
var down;
var left;
var right;

var bobX = 200;
var bobY = 200;
var bobWidth = 30;
var bobHeight = 30;

window.onload = function() {
canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var fps = 200; // frames per second
setInterval(function() {
    updateAll();
    drawAll();
    }, 1000/fps)

};

var drawAll = function() {
    // draw background
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw bob
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(bobX, bobY, bobWidth, bobHeight);
};

var updateAll = function() {

if (up == true) {

    up = false;

}
if (down == true) {
    bobY += 1;
    down = false;
}
if (left == true) {
    bobX -= 1;
    left = false;
}
if (right == true) {
    bobX += 1;
    right = false;
}


};



function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
         up = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        down = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        left = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        right = true;
    }

}
```

I tried doing moving it by one pixel every keypress, but it moves very slowly when I do that.

Comment: Use `requestAnimationFrame`instead of the setInterval and let the character move over time and not per frame.

Comment: I tnink you should increase the timer rate (which will make it update faster). And for the pixels you might try to put some value which will make it move not that much and not that little, like 5 for example.

Comment: @SebastianNette, How about making a movement of element using RAF at **Keydown** Event and stopping the movement at **Keyup** ?

Comment: @RayonDabre That should work too, since the rAF is called when the screen updates, but depending on the implementation you might skip drawing some frames. (e.g. cancel before drawing) so I would instead let it run all the time and maybe keep a dirty flag to check whether or not something changed.

Comment: @SebastianNette but how would that speed up the movement of character ?

Comment: @RayonDabre By letting characters move over time instead of the short interval (which does way too many useless drawings to the canvas). E.g. the time between 2 rAF calls `var elapsed = Date.now()  lastCallTime;` and if you want your character to be able to travel 200 pixel per second you do `elapsed/1000*200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen has maximum refreshrate, usually 60 fps. Some screens can get up to 120fps, but that's a rather rare case.

So what is happening here:

```
var fps = 200; // frames per second
setInterval(function() {
    updateAll();
    drawAll();
    }, 1000/fps)

};
```

The canvas gets redrawn and the position gets updated at a rate which your screen can't catch up with. You simply can't see that your character only moves 1 pixel instead of 10 pixel.

Solution would be to use requestAnimationFrame instead. Which invokes when the screen refreshes:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    updateAll();
    drawAll();
};
animate();
```